# ArgoCD: Provide git commit SHA to Helm values

Tags: git, charts, kubernetes-helm, argocd

Assume you have an `Application` spec inside a cluster which is manage by ArgoCD, like:

```yaml
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Application
metadata:
  name: foo-app
  namespace: argocd
spec:
  destination:
    name: some-cluster
    namespace: foo-namespace
  project: default
  source:
    path: kubernetes/helm
    repoURL: https://github.com/my/great-project.git
    targetRevision: HEAD
```

Now assuming inside the Helm Chart I need access to the checked out Git commit SHA which was used to get the Helm Chart inside `kubernetes/helm`. Like to reference the image name `my-registry.com/my/great-project:<COMMIT_SHA>`.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

According to [build environment](https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user-guide/build-environment/), you should be able to use the environment variable `ARGOCD_APP_REVISION` on your Helm chart.

Comment: I see, but now how to access those environment variables inside of helm?